# Order of work experience

Tags: resume, applications, work-experience

I have a question regarding what order I should place my work experiences on my CV. I have had two part-time jobs at University. I am now going into my final year, so I am still employed at these. This summer I completed an internship, so I wanted to ask in what order I should present them on my CV?

I currently have it in this order (because my internship experience is more relevant for the jobs I am applying for):

Internship June 2017 - August 2017

Part-time job 1  September 2016 - Present

Part-time job 2  October 2015 - Present

This seems slightly odd though, as I am longer working at the internship, but I am still employed at the part-time jobs. LinkedIn automatically puts the internship below the part-time jobs.

*Note:* This is for a UK CV.

Comment: Are the part time jobs relevant to the job being applied for?

Comment: @EdHeal Not as relevant as the internship, but in terms of transferable skills - yes, still relevant.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Might as well turn it into an answer, that's indeed the standard for a (technically reverse) chronological order for resumes. Though I assume that we've had previous questions on this exact topic before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> in what order I should present them on my CV?

I always put jobs in reverse-chronological order, with the end date as the primary key and the start date as the secondary key. I agree that your current order seems odd, and I suspect it would be confusing to the reader.